# SQLite query hanging on join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with 2 tables, survey and syncheader.
Survey has the primary key of SurveyId (Guid) and this is a foreign key in the syncheader table.

The problem I have is that when I join between these tables the sqlite query will hang and return no response (in both Firefox sqlite manager and SQLite2009Pro), my code will return an error when trying to run the query even though it is valid syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE "syncheader" (
    syncheaderid guid not null constraint pkc_syncheader_syncheaderid primary key,
    surveyid guid not null,
    surveydate datetime null,
    syncsurveyorid guid null,
    isdirty boolean null,
    assetid int null,
    syncinspectionid int null,
    inspectionid int null
);
CREATE TABLE survey (
    surveyid guid not null constraint pkc_survey_surveyid primary key,
    assetid int not null,
    sectionid int not null,
    surveydate datetime null,
    syncsurveyorid guid null,
    isdirty boolean null,
    inspectionid int null,
    status int default 0 null
);

SELECT sh.surveyid SurveyID, sh.syncheaderid AS SyncHeaderID, 
sh.surveydate AS SurveyDate, sh.syncsurveyorid AS SyncSurveyorID, 
sh.assetid AS AssetID, sh.inspectionid AS InspectionID, 
sh.syncinspectionid AS SyncInspectionID 
FROM syncheader sh JOIN survey s ON sh.surveyid = s.surveyid 
WHERE sh.isdirty = 1 
AND s.isdirty = 1 
ORDER BY sh.surveydate LIMIT 0, 100
```

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output:

```
0 0 0 SCAN TABLE syncheader1 AS sh (~168 rows)
0 1 1 SEARCH TABLE survey AS s USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_survey_1 (surveyid=?) (~1 rows)
0 0 0 USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "hang"? And what is the error?

Comment: The query appears to be executing but after a considerable amount of time there is still no result being displayed in either of the editors mentioned above. No error message, or result of any kind, appears.

Comment: Run `ANALYZE`, then show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have run ANALYZE and still receive the same results, I have uploaded my results from the EXPLAIN path [here](http://www.filedropper.com/csvexplainresultafteranalyse_1)

Comment: EXPLAIN is not the same as EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I have placed the result of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN [here](http://www.filedropper.com/explainqueryplan_1). Thanks again.

Comment: How large are the two tables? How many result records would you expect to get?

Comment: Survey is 109,771 rows and SyncHeader is 1682 rows. As I am specifying a limit I only require 100 rows (but this behavior occurs even when I limit to 1 row).

Comment: Strange. Please show the schema for these two tables.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the format to include the table structure in my question, I have uploaded the schema for the 2 tables [here](http://www.filedropper.com/tables)

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4b03d/1/0).

Comment: To edit the question, click "edit" and read the help.